# Compiling Python code into an exe file calling just the required DLLs

Tags: python, c++, numpy, exe, cython

There seems to be little information out there on this subject - I have tried `py2exe` to no avail (errors out w/ Python 3.5), as well as `pyinstaller.`  The latter seems to include EVERY extension module installed on the system unless they are specifically excluded during build time, which ends up being 50+ on even a small build.  I have also seen `pyinst` and `cxFreeze` where you can specify which packages to include and it bundles Python with it, BUT I want simple and small.  All the work I do involves AT MOST `NumPy`, `SciPy`, and `Pandas`.  Typically these can all be reduced to `NumPy` only functions, and most complex ones I rewrite in Cython (with `memoryviews`).  Looking around the internet I've found that `python.exe` is a C++ program that only calls `Python.h` and loads `python35.dll` - this suggests something as simple as this C++ code sample would allow one to access all of Python and `NumPy` functionality as so:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <\numpy\core\include\numpy\ required includes>

int
wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    wchar_t *myargs[3] = { argv[0], L"-m", L"myscript.py" };
    return Py_Main(3, myargs);
}
```

Example is from:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/26/cpython-embeddable-zip-file/

Does anyone have a good way or a good reference to generate a small build which includes only what you need for the exe to run?  Or can confirm the above would actually work with modifications?  Much appreciated, I think this skill is a niche subject...

Comment: Maybe you're talking about embedding the Python interpreter? (https://docs.python.org/3.6/extending/index.html#embedding-the-cpython-runtime-in-a-larger-application)

Comment: Yes something like that, searching for embedding Python I stumbled across this project that may work: https://github.com/Who8MyLunch/Python-Embed-Demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can take the dependency, you can use [`boost::python`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html) to help.

There's a full working exemplar app below, which only links `boost_python` and `python2.7` shared libraries. An `-O3` build is only 51K.

**Import a python module:**

You use [`boost::python::exec`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/embedding.html#embedding.boost_python_exec_hpp.introduction) to execute an import statement, importing your python module into a `boost::python::object`

```
bp::object import(const std::string& module, const std::string& path)
{
    bp::object globals = bp::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");

    bp::dict locals;
    locals["module_name"] = module;
    locals["path"]        = path;

    // execute some python code which imports the file
    bp::exec("import imp\n"
             "new_module = imp.load_module(module_name, open(path), path, ('bp', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE))\n",
             globals,
             locals);
    return locals["new_module"];
}

// get an object containing the contents of the file "test.py"
bp::object module = import("test", "test.py");
```

**Get a handle to an element in the python module:**

```
// get a handle to something declared inside "test.py"
bp::object Script = module.attr("Script");
```

**Instantiate an object:**

```
// Instantiate a script object
bp::object script = Script();
```

**Call a member function of `Script`:**

```
// calls Script.run(), passing no arguments
script.attr("run")();
```

**You can also expose C++ code to python:**

Expose a C++ class to the module you just imported using [`boost::python::class`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components.html#high_level_components.boost_python_class_hpp.introduction):

```
struct Foo
{
    void func();
}

bp::object FooWrapper(
    bp::class_<Foo>("Foo")
        .def("func", &Foo::func)
    );

bp::object foo    = FooWrapper(); // instantiate a python wrapped Foo object
bp::object script = Script(foo);  // create a Script instance, passing foo
```

### Working example:

#### test.py

```
class Script(object):
    def __init__(self, ifc):
        print 'created script'
        self.ifc = ifc

    def run(self):
        print 'running'
        self.ifc.execute(5)

    def result(self, i):
        print 'result={}'.format(i)
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

namespace bp = boost::python;

bp::object import(const std::string& module, const std::string& path)
{
    bp::object globals = bp::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");

    bp::dict locals;
    locals["module_name"] = module;
    locals["path"]        = path;

    bp::exec("import imp\n"
             "new_module = imp.load_module(module_name, open(path), path, ('bp', 'U', imp.PY_SOURCE))\n",
             globals,
             locals);
    return locals["new_module"];
}

///////////////////////////

class Runner
{
public:
    void init(bp::object script)
    {
        // capture methods at creation time so we don't have to look them up every time we call them
        _run    = script.attr("run");
        _result = script.attr("result");
    }

    void run()
    {
        _run(); // call the script's run method
    }

    void execute(int i) // this function is called by the python script
    {
        _result(i * 2); // call the script's result method
    }

    bp::object _run;
    bp::object _result;
};

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    // load our python script and extract the Script class
    bp::object module = import("test", "test.py");
    bp::object Script = module.attr("Script");

    // wrap Runner and expose some functions to python
    bp::object RunnerWrapper(
        bp::class_<Runner>("Runner")
            .def("execute", &Runner::execute)
        );

    // create a python wrapped instance of Runner, which we will pass to the script so it can call back through it
    bp::object wrapper = RunnerWrapper();
    bp::object script  = Script(wrapper);

    // extract the runner instance from the python wrapped instance
    Runner& runner = bp::extract<Runner&>(wrapper);

    // initialise with the script, so we can get handles to the script's methods we require
    runner.init(script);

    runner.run();

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2.2)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)

add_executable            (py_embed main.cpp)
target_link_libraries     (py_embed ${Boost_PYTHON_LIBRARY} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(py_embed SYSTEM PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Downloadable source code [here](https://github.com/skebanga/py_embed)

Comment: Thanks @SteveLorimer I'm going to play around with your proof of concept and see where I get... need to study it a bit.  The earlier link I posted using NumPy and C++ and Cython compiled but gives an error - `Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'` so I'll probably mess with yours and see how it goes.